# Azure Devops REST API delete Release

Tags: azure-devops-rest-api

I´m currently trying to delete a release (not release definition) over the REST API of Azure Devops but can´t find anything on how to do this. Already searched the documentary and googled a lot. Hope someone can give me a clue.

As more details where requested here some more details:

I´m showing a list of releases in my app by getting them from the REST API([here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/release/releases/list?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1)).

In that list I want to create a button to delete an item. I searched the documentary ([here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/release/releases/update%20release?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1)) and no result. To delete builds was pretty easy ([here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/builds/delete?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1)), but can´t find anything in the documentary on how to do this with releases.

Comment: Please provide more information. If you add full description I will mark question +1.

Comment: Hope thats clarifies it a bit better what I´m trying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After writing the clarification I tryed to use the same request like in build for the release to delete. This is not documented in the Microsoft documentation but seems to work.
So here is the request that worked:

```
DELETE https://{instance}/{organization}/{project}/_apis/release/releases/{releaseId}?api-version=5.1
```

For {instance} use you server url or the one from Azure Devops.

Answer (score 2):

For this issue, yes, the delete release rest api is not documented in the official documentation.

I tested the rest api you listed in Postman, but returned `404 Not Found` status, release is not deleted:

```
DELETE https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/release/releases/{releaseId}?api-version=5.1
```

[image]

I tested with the following rest api, and the release can be successfully deleted:

```
DELETE https://vsrm.dev.azure.com/{org}/{pro}/_apis/release/releases/{releaseId}?api-version=5.1
```

[image]

This api is tracked from the browser's `Network` by pressing `F12`:

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: In my answer I have used https://dev.azure.com/ from the documentation, on my company we use an on premise server, so different link. But thanks for pointing it out for others.